# Removing nested pscustomobject within Azure Rule JSON

Tags: json, powershell

Been struggling with deleting a nested object within JSON returned from an Azure Alert Rule query.

Thanks to folks here, I've learned how to add a PSCustomObject within another. In this case, (below) to add a webhook action

```json
"actions": [
    {
        "$type": "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Monitoring.Alerts.Models.RuleEmailAction, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Mon.Client",
        "odata.type": "Microsoft.Azure.Management.Insights.Models.RuleEmailAction",
        "sendtoserviceowners": true,
        "customEmails": [
            "email2@domain.com",
            "email1@domain.com"
        ]
    }
]
```

```bsh
$rule.properties.actions += [PSCustomObject]@{
    '$type' = "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Monitoring.Alerts.Models.RuleWebhookAction, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Mon.Client";
    'odata.type' = "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Monitoring.Alerts.Models.RuleWebhookAction";
    serviceuri = "http://www.webhooktest.com"
}
```

Which results in

```json
"actions": [
    {
        "$type": "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Monitoring.Alerts.Models.RuleWebhookAction, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Mon.Client",
        "odata.type": "Microsoft.Azure.Management.Insights.Models.RuleWebhookAction",
        "serviceUri": "http://www.webhooktest.com"
    },
    {
        "$type": "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Monitoring.Alerts.Models.RuleEmailAction, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Mon.Client",
        "odata.type": "Microsoft.Azure.Management.Insights.Models.RuleEmailAction",
        "sendToServiceOwners": false,
        "customEmails": [
            "email2@domain.com",
            "email1@domain.com"
        ]
    }
]
```

I need to be able to remove the webhook and leave the email. If I could add it using `+=`, why does trying to remove it with `-=`

```bsh
$rule.properties.actions -= [PSCustomObject]@{
    '$type' = "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Monitoring.Alerts.Models.RuleWebhookAction, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Mon.Client";
    'odata.type' = "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Monitoring.Alerts.Models.RuleWebhookAction";
    serviceuri = "http://www.webhooktest.com"
}
```

result in

> result in [System.Object[]] does not contain a method named 'op_Subtraction'

I've not had luck with the `Remove()` method either. What will work?

Comment: Just because a class implements the addition operator doesn't imply that it also would implement the subtraction operator. And even if it did, the subtraction probably wouldn't work anyway, b/c the new object you're creating is equal to the exisiting one, but not identical with it, so you'd try to remove an object that isn't present in the first place. Use something like this: `$rule.properties.actions = @($rule.properties.actions | Where-Object {$_.serviceuri -ne 'http://www.webhooktest.com'})`. Adjust the `Where-Object` condition to your needs.

Comment: That worked! So I had to treat it as an array, query it to just return what I wanted, and reassign it to $rule.properties.actions. I thought that would be invalid since I was working with key/value pairs. However, it was still an array, one containing two elements consisting of key/value pairs. Do I have that right?

Comment: Tip for the future: You can avoid playing with JSON by converting them to powershell objects. Try using `ConvertFrom-Json`. Refer to this for further information: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/10/08/playing-with-json-and-powershell/

Comment: You're working with objects and object arrays, not just key/value pairs (i.e. hashtables). But yes, the structure from which you wanted to remove one element was an array with two nested objects.

Comment: @unrealsoul007 That's what I would normally do, except the JSON payload returned from Azure fails ConvertFrom-Json. This is pretty much the norm. Appreciate everyone for the help and advice.